# How efficient is jQuery $.get?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I have a `.json` file that is 50MB and 84 000 lines.  I am using the code below to load it into the variable `2002data`. At first I was waiting for a while as expected but when I added an alert before `$.get` nothing was coming up.  Am I doing something wrong or is this normal?

```
alert('starting 2002_results.json'); // This alert isn't showing up...
$.get('2002_results.json', function(2002data));
alert('2002 done');
```

Just in case this makes a difference, here is the first 2 and last 2 lines of the `.json` file.

```
{"2002Results": [

{"st_is_str":"01006000102","parm_desc":"ALKALINITY, TOTAL"},

{"st_id":{"station_id":"18349002002","name":"Madawaska River","location":"Madawaska Blvd, Arnprior","first_year":1966,"last_year":2010,"total_years":45,"missed_years":0,"long_coord":-76.34968485,"lat_coord":-76.34968485},"parm_desc":"ZINC,  UNFILTERED TOTAL"},

]}
```

..and this goes on for a while.

If there is something more efficient I can use what is it? (Just a name would be good, I'll figure the rest out)

Comment: `alert()`s will block anything that follows them. So, as long as the dialog with `'starting ...'` is showing, `$.get()` won't have actually started. Try [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log) instead of `alert()` for less invasive debugging. Also note that [`$.get()` is asynchronous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call), so the result is only available within the callback `function` you give it.

Comment: transferring 50MB of data should be a big no.... you should do some server side processing and sent back only the very necessary data to the client

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm starting to realize that. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Loading things:

You shouldn't load 50mb of data at once. That is a huge server load and too time consuming. Instead, evaluate what the user needs to see at the time and just load enough to handle that. Loading on scroll, loading on click, or pagination are common approaches.

### Syntax errors!

You have a syntax error. Change your code to:

```
$.get('2002_results.json').then(function(resp) {
  alert('2002 done');
});
```

or:

```
$.get('2002_results.json', function(resp) {
  alert('2002 done');
});
```

You should check your console (probably f12 key). `function(2002data));` is not valid javascript. If you have a syntax error, nothing in the script will run.

Also, your JSON is invalid. Here is the corrected JSON:

```
[
  {
    "2002Results": [
      {
        "st_is_str":"01006000102",
        "parm_desc":"ALKALINITY, TOTAL"
      },
      {
        "st_id":{
          "station_id":"18349002002",
          "name":"Madawaska River",
          "location":"Madawaska Blvd, Arnprior",
          "first_year":1966,
          "last_year":2010,
          "total_years":45,
          "missed_years":0,
          "long_coord":-76.34968485,
          "lat_coord":-76.34968485
        },
        "parm_desc":"ZINC,  UNFILTERED TOTAL"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

There were some misplaced commas. http://jsonlint.com/ is a good tool.

**[Live demo of correct code and JSON (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/svMYx6BA85t2PtnF8x3Q?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried using your code and now I get the first alert but not "2002 done".

Comment: I checked the console and `event.returnValue is deprecated` came up.  Is `$.get` asynchronous? I ask because Google Maps loaded and the script for that is below the `$.get` code.

Comment: @user3210944 I'm pretty sure that's because your json is invalid.

Comment: @user3210944 yes, it is asynchronous unless you set it to false.

Comment: So your saying that the JSON objects in the file is invalid? Sorry, I'm really new at this.

Comment: @user3210944 don't forget to mark my answer as accepted (the checkmark to the left of it) if you appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah thanks for reminding me.  When I tried before it said I had to wait a bit.